# How to show ripple effect over text of the button only?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to display the ripple effect over the text of the button only (the button is transparent). InkWell or default TextButton/ElevatedButton animation doesn't work in this case because it animates background color only and keeps the text color static. What I am trying to archive is the opposite.
Important: changing textColor with setState doesn't work in my case as I need the animation to be displayed. Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: it would be good to share your code what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think this package will be useful in your case :
https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foQTKCQqVWk

if you don't want to use this package and want to create your own special animation check the page below:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/implicit-animations